# When exactly was the RS-232 standard issued?

Tags: rs232, standard, history

This year is 50th anniversary of RS-232 standard. Despite its age it is still used nowadays, and I work in company that has to deal with it.

So we have a half-serious idea to celebrate the exact day the standard was issued. Does anyone knows that date? Maybe someone has printed copy to look into?

*Though this questions relates more to history than to electrical engineering, I think that this site is the best place to find people who might have an answer. I've [asked this question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/383942/when-exactly-was-the-rs-232-standard-issued), it was closed as off-topic, but I was advised to ask here.*

Comment: Many people don't know that "RS" stands for "Recommended Standard", which implies its preliminary status. Nowadays it is called EIA-232, but I seem to be the only person who uses that name.

Comment: I don't know the date, and probably you have already googled so it's hard that I'll find, but tell me if you find it :)

Comment: @stevenvh actually the last version (since 1988 :D) of the name is TIA-232-F, as the standard is mantained by Telecommunication Industry Association: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232); anyway, it's a traditional name that's hard to change between the users

Comment: @clabacchio - Actually it's EIA/TIA-232. EIA and TIA are different organizations, but it was EIA which changed the RS-232 name to EIA-232.

Comment: @stevenvh no problem, my intention wasn't to fight for the attribution of the name; what I think is that RS-232 is so popular among users that probably the newest name will be used only by a few people; somehow the same reason why you say Wi-Fi instead 8f 802.11/whatever

Comment: @stevenvh anyway, take a [look](http://www.ecaus.org/eia/site/index.html)...seems that EIA has been splitted in different associations...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS232 has some history

Comment: When you do, toast at 2:32.

Comment: I wrote TIA and they're considering incorporating this into their annual event this year, TIA2012.  Still looking for the actual date....

Comment: I got an interesting, tentative response from TIA, suggesting that while the connector was introduced in 1962, the original EIA-232 Standard was published in 1960.  It looks like in May of that year.  Does that make sense?

"EIA-232 - Complete Document
        Revision / Edition: 60      Chg:      Date: 05/00/60
        INTERFACE BETWEEN DATA TERMINAL EQUIPMENT & DATA"

Comment: in that case we would be lost! O.O

Comment: Oh, no... Well, anyway, we can celebrate its 52th anniversary. @nealmcb you can post an answer, I'll accept it. By the way, isn't 05/00/60 a typo?

Comment: Thanks - I'm still digging for a bit more clarity, but will post when I have something a bit more solid....